# Undeleting project fails

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Somehow one of my google cloud projects got deleted. I don't know why and how but I got an email which explained that I have one month to reactivate it without a notice who deleted it initially.
Now I want to undelete this project with the gcloud command:

```
gcloud projects undelete <projectId>
```

but it fails with the following message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.projects.undelete) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Parent
>   organization  is not active
>   - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure   violations:
>     - description: Parent organization  is not active

If I try to describe the given organization id with the command:

```
gcloud organizations describe <organizationId>
```

it fails with something like "This organization does not exist".

I also tried to undelete it with the Google Cloud Console but it also fails (without a real error message).

How can I undelete my project? And if this is a serious issue, how can I contact Google Support without having the Gold Support membership?

Comment: Did you request support for restoring the project?
If not you can open a PIT case [1] and supply the project number. After you create the issue provide me with a link to it so that help can be provided for restoring the project.

[1]: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164

Comment: @JMD Thank you. I requested support and they already restored the project.

Comment: I am happy to hear that. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you’re getting means that you are trying to undelete a project that is still part of an organization that no longer exists.

As the organization no longer exists it doesn’t allow you to restore the project, since projects belong to an organization, as can be seen in the GCP [resource hierarchy tree](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy).

The following [documentation 1](https://cloud.google.com/support/) and [documentation 2](https://cloud.google.com/support/?options=premium-support#options) provide information for the support options that you can have.